# Removing queued Javascript messages in the event loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-loop

In Javascript, if an event is triggered and the corresponding callback is added to the message queue of the Javascript engine event loop. Is it possible to remove it from the queue through Javascript code?

Note that the events are called in high frequency, so it may be added to the event queue before any Javascript code is executed. I didn't see a description saying that `removeEventListener` actually goes through the message queue and remove corresponding events; want to double check if `removeEventListener` actually does that and such function is implemented the same way across all Javascript engines.

Comment: _Is it possible to remove it from the queue?_ Sure, [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Can you give a use case for wanting to do this?

Comment: Say I want to prevent a callback get called twice, I can add a flag in the callback to check if it is already called, but want to know if there is other ways to do it properly.

Comment: Note that the events are called in high frequency, so it may be added to the event queue before I run any javascript code. I just don't see a description saying that removeEventListener actually goes through the message queue and remove corresponding events; want to double check if it is implemented the same way among all javascript engines.

Comment: @hindmost Can you provide documentation for your claim that `removeEventListener` removes events which are already queued up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Javascript does not offer any direct access to the event queue.  You can listen for events (often with `.addEventListener()` or by registering callbacks and, when it is their turn, that event will fire and your callback will get called.  Or, some listeners can be removed with `.removeEventListener()` or by canceling a specific operation (like `clearTimeout()`), but, there is no direct access to managing the event queue.

You would likely have to somehow have native code inside the VM in order to do that and how to do it would be non-standard and specific to a particular Javascript VM.

If you really just want to be able to easily prevent a callback from getting called more than once, then you can create a little stub that will do that for you.

```
function callOnce(fn) {
   var called = false;
   return function() {
      if (!called) {
          called = true;
          return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      }
   }
}


// create a callOnce function stub for myFunction
var cb = callOnce(myFunction);

obj1.addEventListener("click", cb);
obj2.addEventListener("click", cb);
obj3.addEventListener("click", cb);
```

`myFunction` will only ever get called once whenever the first event calls it.  After that, it will be blocked by the callOnce stub that was created when `cb` was defined.

Comment: If i do removeEventListener does the corresponding messages put in the queue get removed? Or it only prevents future events trigger?

Comment: @Gooly - There's no way to tell from the outside as that's up to the individual JVM implementation and frankly, it's immaterial as it doesn't make any difference either.  If you tell us what problem you're really trying to solve rather than ask these theoretical questions, we could probably help better.

Comment: @Gooly - In another comment somewhere else you mentioned preventing a callback being called twice.  You can very easily make a callback stub that prevents any callback from getting called twice and then whenever you want to register a single use callback, you just do something like `obj.addEventListener("eventname", callOnce(myFunc))` and the callOnce wrapper handles it for you.

Comment: So removeEventListener probably won't do the trick if it is already in the queue, is that correct? If callOnce function is not ideal for my situation, is adding a flag in the callback a standard way to do this?

Comment: `callOnce()` is simpler than adding a flag because it's a reusable flag mechanism.  See the example implementation I put in my answer.  In the future, you will get quicker and richer answers if you describe the  actual problem you're trying to solve in your question rather than ask theoretical questions about the solution you are pursuing.

Comment: Yes, callOnce is more elegant, but in many cases when you are just modifying a small part of some large code base, adding such general function is a hassle. The question is also more based on curiosity. But thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. its possible to unbind an event from object.

- if you have used `addEventListener` to attach event then use `removeEventListener` to remove it.
- if you have used jQuery `.bind()` then use `.unbind()` to remove it.
- if you have used jQuery `.on()` then use `.off()` to remove it.
- if you use `attachEvent`, you can use `detachEvent()`.
- If you use `onclick` or other similar functions then you can remove them by simply setting it to null.

  > ex. obj.onclick = null.

Comment: I added a few more descriptions, I am considering cases when the event is already triggered. I wonder if the examples you gave still works.

Comment: The question is not how to unbind (what an unfortunate expression jQuery has given us) an event from an object, but how to manage events **already triggered** and waiting for execution.